# Select tag helper to filter index

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, tag-helpers

I'm trying to use a select tag helper to filter a list of moves by difficulty and type. So far I have a working dropdown, but I have no idea how to redirect the selected value to the index method in my controller.

This is what I have

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Taijitan.Models.Domain.Move>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Moves";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<div class="form-group">
     //Returns filter1
    <select asp-items="@ViewData["Difficulty"] as List<SelectListItem>" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Select Difficulty --</option>
    </select>
     //Returns filter2
    <select asp-items="@ViewData["Type"] as List<SelectListItem>" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The dropdown list is supposed to return the selected value to the index method, which takes a string as filter.

**Controller**

```
    public IActionResult Index(string filter, string filter2)
    {
        IEnumerable<Move> Moves = null;
        if (filter == null && filter2 == null){
            Moves = _MoveRepository.GetAll();
        }
        else if (filter != null && filter2 == null)
        {
            Moves = _MoveRepository.GetByDifficulty(int.Parse(filter));
        }
        else if (filter == null && filter2 != null))
        {
            Moves = _MoveRepository.GetByType(filter);
        }
        else if (filter != null && filter2 != null))
        {
            Moves = _MoveRepository.GetByType(filter).Where(m => m.Difficulty == int.Parse(filter2);
        }
        ViewData["Type"] = GetTypesAsSelectList();
        ViewData["Difficulty"] = GetDifficultiesAsSelectList();
        return View(Moves);
    }
```

**Method which creates the displayed selectList (almost same for DifficultyList)**

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetTypesAsSelectList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> TypesList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (Move move in _MoveRepository.GetAll().Distinct())
    {
        TypesList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = Move.Type, Value = Move.Type });
    }

    return TypesList;
```

I'm stuck at figuring out how to pass the selected value of the dropdown lists as filter and filter2 to the index.

**EDIT**

I've added a form element and this button:

```
<a asp-controller="Move" asp-action="Index" asp-route-filter="" asp-route-filter2="" class="btn btn-default">Filter</a>
```

I can't figure out how to get the value of the first list in asp-route-filter, and the value of the second list in asp-route-filter2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One core piece to a HTML form submit is the `<form></form>` element. Based on your question, I am assuming your form will be doing a `GET` instead of a `POST`. I assume this because the default action of a controller is a `GET`. Another is the `SUBMIT` button itself (unless you plan on submitting the form via javascript or other means).

You're also missing the `asp-for=""` which is a fancy way to populate the `Name` and `Id` of an element of a view. For your example, you would use `filter` and `filter2` as the values. Though I would refactor those names in the future. The `Name` attribute allows the model binder to bind elements of the request to the controller's parameters.

With this in mind, your below form would look as follows (note the added `FORM` element, `BUTTON` element, and the addition of `asp-for=""`).

```
@model IEnumerable<Taijitan.Models.Domain.Move>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Moves";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<form method="GET">
<div class="form-group">
     //Returns filter1
    <select asp-items="@ViewData["Difficulty"] as List<SelectListItem>" class="form-control" asp-for="filter">
        <option value="">-- Select Difficulty --</option>
    </select>
     //Returns filter2
    <select asp-items="@ViewData["Type"] as List<SelectListItem>" class="form-control" asp-for="filter2">
        <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
    </select>
    <a asp-controller="Move" asp-action="Index" asp-route-filter="" asp-route-filter2="" class="btn btn-default">Filter</a>
</div>
</form>
```

You can use the `@Html.Helpers` for these elements as well. That's your choice. The results are the same.

Comment: I've added the form element and added a button like this
`<a asp-controller="Move" asp-action="Index" asp-route-filter="" asp-route-filter2="" class="btn btn-default">Filter</a>`, but I can't figure out how to get the value of the first list in asp-route-filter, and the value of the second list in asp-route-filter2

Comment: I believe you're also missing an `asp-for=""` I will update my answer